# Stripping characters off each element of an array/set in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, set

I have a HashSet that prints as follows:

```
[Category:Porch of the Cathedral of Palermo, Category:Side views of the Cathedral of Palermo, Category:Church towers of the Cathedral of Palermo, Category:Saint Rosalia by Vincenzo Vitaliano, Category:Piazza del Duomo (Palermo)]
```

And I need to strip the "Category:" characters off each element of the set, to produce the output:

```
[Porch of the Cathedral of Palermo, Side views of the Cathedral of Palermo, Church towers of the Cathedral of Palermo, Saint Rosalia by Vincenzo Vitaliano, Piazza del Duomo (Palermo)]
```

What is the simplest way to do this (in Java)? I am currently using a HashSet (needed it to ensure the elements were unique) but I can just convert it to an ArrayList or whatever works best for this task.

Comment: What have you tried? You should include stuff that you attempted to do instead of relying on us to fix the issue instantly.

Comment: Change the `toString()` method of the element class to not prefix `"Category:"`. Alternatively, write your own method for stringyfying the `Set`. Why do you even care? The `toString` of a `Set` is for debug use, not for end-user display.

Comment: @Andreas I need to use the Set later to display these to a user, and the prefixes are received from an external API. But you are right, I should do this before even adding the items to the Set. I have changed my code to do that, but the replace(x, y) method was very helpful regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way is: Replace the `"Category:"` with empty String. You are already calling `toString()` of the `HashSet`.

```
System.out.println(set.toString().replace("Category:", ""));
```

Output:

```
Before: [Category:Side views of the Cathedral of Palermo, Category:Porch of the Cathedral of Palermo]
After: [Side views of the Cathedral of Palermo, Porch of the Cathedral of Palermo]
```

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly. :)

Comment: I tried to do so, but it tells me I need to wait a few more minutes. Will do it later!